# Why there is a SytaxError when pushing an exec() function into an input()

Tags: python, exec, python-2.x, ctf

There is a `netcat` CTF task where it is needed to get the flag via an RCE (the most simple and obvious variant for me is `exec()`)

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Apr 28 2021, 17:39:59)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux2

>>> print input()
pow(2, 3) # No problems with functions
8

>>> print input()
None # Can print None values
None

>>> print input()
eval('1 + 1')
2

>>> print input()
eval('1 + 1') # eval() works
2

>>> x = 1
>>> print input()
eval('x + 1') # eval() with local variables involved also works
2

>>> print input()
exec('') # Even empty exec() causes an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    exec('') # Even empty exec() causes an error
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> print input()
exec('import os') # exec() call causes an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    exec('import os') # exec() call causes an error
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to push an `exec()` with `input()` called in Python 2.7? (Switching the Python version or changing executable `print input()` cannot be done)

**UPD**

I need something like this:

```
>>> print input()
exec('import os\nprint os.name') # I need a similar RCE in this CTF task, so eval() is not suitable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    exec('import os\nprint os.name') # I need a similar RCE in this CTF task, so eval() is not suitable
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Why do you think that `1 + 1` or an empty line is a legal statement in the command shell you invoke with `exec`?

Comment: @Prune Well, I found nothing about this in the docs. I mean the problem is not in the starement inside `exec()` itself (look in the UPD - without print input() it executes with no errors (as I wrote, the executed “print input()” at the beginning cannot be overridden)

Comment: [The doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) clearly says that you must supply an executable statement.  Neither `1 + 1` nor the empty string is an executable statement.

Comment: @Prune You are right about `1 + 1` and empty input, I will edit the question. But `exec(‘import os\nprint os.name’)` is a valid executable statement, so question stays unanswered.

Comment: I have extended the answer to explain why `'exec "import os;print os.name"'` is not acceptable to `input()` and to suggest an alternative approach that avoids both `input()` and `exec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
>>> print input()
exec('1 + 1')
```

do

```
>>> print input()
eval('1 + 1')
```

and you will get the output `2` that you expect. `exec()` expects executable statements; `eval()` expects an expression, which is what `1+1` is. Though this is simpler and equivalent:

```
>>> print input()
1 + 1
```

I must admit I have no idea what a CTF task is, or why it needs to execute RTE code, whatever that is, but given that your real requirement is not to produce the result of `1 + 1` but rather the value of `os.name`, it might suit your purpose better to avoid futzing around the corner cases of the obsolete `input()` function and simply do, as a command line,

```
python -c "import os;print(os.name)"
```

which (on my system) produces the output

```
nt
```

and will work in every version of Python.

The reason why the Python 2 `input()` function cannot be made to do what you want, is that in Python 2

- `exec` is a statement, not a function.
- `input()` is roughly equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`: it will accept expressions but not statements.

Comment: Can `eval` somehow execute a single-string script (I should mention again that it is a CTF task and I need to access the `os` module with a single line that should contain RCE code) like this: `exec('import os\nprint os.name')`?

Comment: Perhaps use multi-statement syntax instead?  Replace the newline with a semicolon.  This is working for me under Python 3.8.  (Please note that 2.7 was deprecated 18 months ago.)